# Hide REST methods from SOAP WCF Client

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I created a simple WCF Service interface:

```
namespace ApiDoc.SampleApi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contract
    /// </summary>
    /// <webMethodsPrefix>Web</webMethodsPrefix>
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "apidoc.sampleapi.com", Name = "SampleApi")]
    public interface IService
    {

        [WebGet( UriTemplate = "Add?value1={value1}&value2={value2}&apiKey={apiKey}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        AddRs AddWithHttpGet(int value1, int value2, string apiKey);

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Add", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        AddRs Add(AddRq rq);
    }
}
```

In this case it is just a simple Add operation.
It works well for Xml, Soap and Json.  Both Get and Post.

The issue I am having is in Soap when I create a Service Reference to this service.  I can call both functions "Add" and "AddWithHttpGet", while I only would like to see "Add".

I originally thought it was related to using "OperationContract" attribute, but it seems like it is not used any longer.  I tried adding this attribute only to POST Add, but it doesn't make any difference. I am using ASP.NET 4.0.

Another solution would be to create a different IService for Soap, but I would rather keep this all in one interface.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="jsonHttpBinding" />
                <binding name="xmlHttpBinding" />
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="ApiDoc.SampleApi.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ApiDocSampleApiBehavior">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/ApiDoc.SampleApi/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint name="soap" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="apidoc.sampleapi.com" contract="ApiDoc.SampleApi.IService" lockAttributes="bindingNamespace" />
                <endpoint name="json" address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="apidoc.sampleapi.com" bindingConfiguration="jsonHttpBinding" contract="ApiDoc.SampleApi.IService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" />
                <endpoint name="xml" address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="apidoc.sampleapi.com" bindingConfiguration="xmlHttpBinding" contract="ApiDoc.SampleApi.IService" behaviorConfiguration="XmlBehavior" />
                <endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="apidoc.sampleapi.com" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
                    <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="XmlBehavior">
                    <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ApiDocSampleApiBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
    </system.serviceModel>
...
```

Comment: Quick question --> Could you browse to your REST endpoint from IE without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a separate interface.

Think of your interface like a real contract between two parties. You are using it to define what operations are available to a client. If it's in the contract, it's available.

Instead of looking for some sort "invisible ink" that would make certain parts of the contract available to certain clients, I'd simply create two contracts.

Comment: Total agreement - it's not like you are offering one endpoint across two transports, these are fundamentally different mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confussed.  The `OperationContractAttribute` is required.  A `WebGetAttribute` on it's own shouldn't do anything, as the method is not expossed as an operation.

As for hiding an operation, that is not possable either.  If the interface is your contract, and you definatly want two different contracts then you will need two different interfaces.

If you don't want to duplicate your code then you can still use inheritace.  Have one interace define your SOAP operation `Add` and then inherit from that to add `AddWithHttpGet`.  Then by targeting the different interfaces in your endpoints, the SOAP endpoint would have one operation and REST endpoint would have two.

Answer (score 0):

try this you want hide webmethod form soap header in c#

```
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare), WebMethod]
    public string Operation(RIL_OB_MSG RIL_OB_MSG)
    {
    }
```